# Excel add-in NOT using Visual Studio and/or deploying to AppSource?

Tags: excel, office-js, excel-addins

I have located the Add-in folder on my computer and copied manually the [demo app](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ABhpzZ7WdNBKTf8&id=F797AA0B612A41DF%2124627&cid=F797AA0B612A41DF) explained in this [video](https://channel9.msdn.com/series/officejs/End-to-End-Walkthrough-of-Excel-JavaScript-Add-in-Development).

However when I try to open the `Stock sample data` Excel spreadsheet, I get the following error:

`ADD-IN ERROR
This add-in is no longer available: add-ins inserted during development are only available during debugging from Visual Studio. Please open your project in Visual Studio and re-run your application, or deploy your add-in into a valid catalog and re-inser`

Isn't it possible to create an add-in just by using html/javascript files and a manifest?
or am I looking at the wrong folder/file?

EDIT:
I have tried the 2 solutions suggested here:

- https://xomino365.com/2016/03/15/getting-started-locally-with-a-basic-o365-word-add-in-no-web-hosting/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins

ie using localhost trick or sharing with myself, I still can not see my add-in in Developer/Add-ins/Shared Folder

Comment: If this is a javascript question please label it as such.

Comment: Add-ins don't work like that unless your in a testing environment.  More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/add-in-manifests?tabs=tabid-1

Answer (score 0):

Actually I managed to resolve my issue by using the first solution indicated in the EDIT: using `\\localhost\C$\Users\etc...`  Now my add-in appears in the trusted add-ins catalog.

Wasn't working because I had done a spelling mistake `$C` instead of `C$`

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. repair ms office and then it'll work hopefully. I my case it worked after I repair the office package